# Transpose table with categorical data

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have the following data in excel extracted from SQL Server:

```
category label value
A        green 2
A        red   1
A        blue  4
B        green 0
B        red   3
B        blue  2
```

How it can be transposed as follows (preferably within power query)?

```
category green red blue
A        2     1   4
B        0     3   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually transposing, you're pivoting.

Pivot field `label`, with field `value` in values:

```
= Table.Pivot(#"Previous Step", List.Distinct(#"Previous Step"[label]), "label", "value", List.Sum)
```

**EDIT**:

With strings in the `value` field, simply choose not to aggregate the values:

```
= Table.Pivot(#"Previous Step", List.Distinct(#"Previous Step"[label]), "label", "value")
```

This will return an error if you have multiple string values per row / column combination, though. In that case, you may wish to combine values:

```
= Table.Pivot(#"Previous Step", List.Distinct(#"Previous Step"[label]), "label", "value", each Text.Combine(_, ", "))
```

Comment: Thanks @Olly, does it apply when the values are string (not integers)?
I have string values. Transpose is working, but the new table has all error values

Comment: You can't aggregate strings, so just return the values without aggregation - have edited answer.

Comment: ```= Table.Pivot(#"Previous Step", List.Distinct(#"Previous Step"[label]), "label", "value")``` 
this works without aggregation